# Django Error - Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to create a reset password functionality in my application and added the following lines in my `urls.py`.

`urls.py`

```
url(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^resetpassword/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete'),
```

But when I enter my email id on reset password, it is showing an error which I am not able to understand. `Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '`I have gone through some of the suggestions but none are working. Could anyone any help me with this error?

See the below image:

[image]

I

Comment: Please describe the steps you took to trigger the error.

Comment: Seems like I have resolved this `error` by updating this url `url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'),`

Comment: I just added a name to it but now it is showing connection refused :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django needs to know how to resolve the URL from the name used in the `url` template tag. You should add the name to this line:

```
 url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
```

So it becomes:

```
 url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

See more about reverse resolution here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Comment: I have done the same thing but now it is saying connection refused :/

Comment: Is that when you click on the link or load the page - the application is still up?  What is it you see now, is there a URL in the location window?

Comment: When my enter my email id and hit `reset my password`

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla connection refused means your urls.py is now working but only sending the confirmation email fails

Answer (score 1):

`<uidb64>/<token>/` add "//" to your url and it should work

Comment: You need to add password_reset_confirm url into your urls.py (at the top of any other included urls). Please check the urls.py module inside demo app example for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to fix the error. Your regex is too strict, it's only allowing up to 20 characters. Refer to the following link for more information https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31913.

I changed the url to the below and it worked
`path(r'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',`